# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources in audio play()

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I intend to play an audio file from an external url in my js code, but I keep getting this error of `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.` in google chrome and `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.` in firefox.

And here is my code:

```
const sound = new Audio("https://soundcloud.com/saba-a-744718954/tick-1");

button.addEventListener("click", soundHandler);

function soundHandler() {
  sound.play()
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I try your code with this audio (audio.bfmtv.com), and it's work very well :

So you have problem with you audio link !

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Click here to start audio</h1>`;

const sound = new Audio("https://audio.bfmtv.com/bfmbusiness_128.mp3?aw_0_1st.playerId=AudioPlayer_Web_Next");

appDiv.addEventListener("click", soundHandler);

function soundHandler() {
  sound.play()
}
```

You can try it here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wlfkh2?file=index.html

Answer (score 2):

The URL passed to the `Audio` element has to resolve to some audio.

You're passing it the URL to an HTML document!